# Add Multidimensional Array To List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a multidimensional double array with any number of rows and columns:

```
var values = new double[rows, columns];
```

I also have a list of double arrays:

```
var doubleList = new List<double[]>();
```

Now, I would like to add each column in the multidimensional array to the list. How do I do that? I wrote this to illustrate what I want, but it does not work as I am violation the syntax.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    doubleList.Add(values[:,i];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new array for each column and copy each value to it.
Either with a simple for-loop (like the other answers show) or with LINQ:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    double[] column = Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
        .Select(row => values[row, i]).ToArray();
    doubleList.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: Or `doubleList=Enumerable.Range(0,columns).Select(col=>Enumerable.Range(0,rows).Select(row=>values[row,col]).ToArray()).ToList();` if you really hate `for` loops.

Comment: Or even `var doubleList = (from c in Enumerable.Range(0, columns) select (from r in Enumerable.Range(0, rows) select values[r, c]).ToArray()).ToList();` ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = new double[rows, columns];
var doubleList = new List<double[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    var tmpArray = new double[rows];
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; i++)
    {
        tmpArray[j] = values[j, i];
    }
    doubleList.Add(tmpArray);
}
```

Comment: Ofc. iterate over each dimension. Just thought there was (or should be) a more elegant solution - maybe with LINQ.

Comment: @TimPohlmann An array is a collection too. LINQ works fine with arrays.

Comment: See Deniss_E's answer for a LINQ solution. LINQ does not work on arrays, though, which makes it a bit tricky.

Comment: @Dennis_E linq doesn't work well directly with multi-dimensional arrays, as your own answer makes use of. I prefer one extreme or the other (all linq or no linq) myself, but all three answers produce the same results.

Answer (score 2):

With the approach you were taking:

```
for(int i = 0; i != columns; ++i)
{
    var arr = new double[rows];
    for(var j = 0; j != rows; ++j)
        arr[j] = values[j, i];
    doubleList.Add(arr);
}
```

Build up the each array, per row, then add it.

Another approach would be:

```
var doubleList = Enumerable.Range(0, columns).Select(
  i => Enumerable.Range(0, rows).Select(
    j => values[j, i]).ToArray()
  ).ToList()
```

Which some would consider more expressive in defining what is taken (`values[j, i]` for a sequence of `i` inner sequence of `j`) and what is done with them (put each inner result into an array and the result of that into a list).